# Reversing a list of lists

Tags: list, f#

I want to make a function which takes an `int list list` and returns an `int list list` but with each list reverted. Example:

```
[[1;2;3];[4;5;6]] -> [[6;5;4];[3;2;1]]
```

The function I've come up with so far is missing something I can't quite see and returns:

```
 [[4;5;6];[6;5;4]]
```

It looks like this:

```
let revrev lstOfLst = 
    let revrevInner lst = 
        List.fold (fun rst x -> x::rst) [] lst
    List.fold (fun rst x -> x::[(revrevInner x)]) [] lstOfLst
```

Comment: just curious, why not `List.rev >> List.map List.rev`?

Comment: I'm trying to get to understand `fold` better, but for a succinct function, your suggestion is definitely better. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading through my function again, I noticed that I don't use rst in the first fold. The function should look like this:

```
let revrev lstOfLst = 
    let revrevInner lst = 
        List.fold (fun rst x -> x::rst) [] lst
    List.fold (fun rst x -> (revrevInner x)::rst) [] lstOfLst
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let revRev lstOfLst =
    List.fold (fun s x -> (List.rev x) :: s) [] lstOfLst
```